# Bootstrap based framework for page layout building

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have page, where user can dynamicly add\del\change rows and panels.

I saw something similar in Graphana:

[image]
User can add rows and panels inside row dynamicly, also can change wide of panels (in "spans").

Does any similar frameworks already exist?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Laravel` framework with some twist, you can get into what you want and also use `bootstrap` as you want for styling.